# Casper JS won't waitForSelector using id

Tags: javascript, testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm writing my first casperjs tests and I run throught a problem. I need to wait for an element to be in my DOM. It works great using a verbose selector but can't find it via it's id.

With this HTML:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li data-ng-if="!connectedUser &amp;&amp; currentRoom" data-ng-class="$route.current.activetab == 'login' ? 'active' : ''">
          <a href="/login" data-translate="NAV.ITEM_SIGN_IN" id="toto"></a>
      </li>
      ...
  </ul>
```

And this JavaScript:

```
casper.waitForSelector(".nav > li > a:first-child", function () {
        test.comment(".nav > li > a:first-child OK !");
        casper.capture(config.screensFolder + "verbose_selector.png");
    }, null, 15000)

    .waitForSelector("#toto", function () {
        test.comment("#toto OK !");
        casper.capture(config.screensFolder + "id_selector.png");
    }, null, 15000)

    .run(function () {
        test.done();
    });
```

I get this output:

> Verbose OK !
>
> FAIL "#toto" still did not exist in 15000ms
>       type: uncaughtError
>       file: test/login3.js
>       error: "#toto" still did not exist in 15000ms

Comment: Nobody has any idea ? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after tryong this for hours ! I finally realised that you need to put the element type before the id like this `button#toto`.